# General openMP - thread speeds are different

Tags: c++, openmp

I have an openMP program, where a for loop is parallelised.
Everything works as it should, except the master thread is many, many times faster than the rest of the threads... For example, when running with 4 threads, thread 0 finishes long before the other ones, but they are executing the same code, with almost the same amount of work.

Can this be because of resource handling by Windows, swapping tasks in and out of the threads used by the program, causing the slowdown? 
Or is it more likely that my code is the problem? I just wanna make sure I don't waste time looking for an error in my program, if this is an unavoidable problem caused by the OS...

Comment: It's difficult to say what is provide bad behavior without any real code exposed. However, if you want a reference see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355559/openmp-slower-more-than-one-threads-cant-figure-out.

Comment: I think I have too much code for it to be usefull to post... 

The question is really about the general behavior of openMP: Can one count on each thread to be equally fast?

Comment: Unless you spend the time to distill your code to the essential elements without throwing out the important parts your question will likely get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why the thread has priority, it could be an issue between the OpenMP runtime and the OS. Which compiler are you using? How are you measuring when the threads terminate?

To improve the performance of your OpenMP parallel for in this case, I would use the dynamic scheduling policy with the [schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Scheduling_clauses) directive. If the master thread is getting more cycles from the CPU, it will also do more work in this case. In general, you can't count on each thread to be equally fast, but if you are observing orders of magnitude differences, it sounds like a bad clash between the runtime and OS.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for... 
It turns out that after some experimentation, it has become clear that the less processes running in the OS in the background, the more equal the threads run. 
When using all available cores, one of the threads is always significantly slower. 
I will test this out on a node on a node on a supercomputer, with 32 cores and see if the performance isn't more uniform, when it is not running a big operating system using a bunch of resources..

Comment: In terms of contention, you should also pay attention to process binding.

Getting threads to be exactly the same speed may not always be practical, so I do recommend considering dynamic scheduling within OpenMP.

Answer (score 0):

Look thread execution is dependent on many things so there may be many possibility like is there any locking machanism is there or not or resource availability like when the thread complete the job it must release the resources. Many more factors are there. So what I suggest is use a tool called vtune and profile your code it will give you clear idea where is your thread wasting the time and why. I hope it helps.